# Initialize a lambda function in the body of a class constructor

Tags: c++, lambda, constructor, member-initialization

I can compile the following code without any problem (using gcc 11.1.0):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Func>
class K {
    Func f;
public:
    K(Func _f): f{_f} {};
    void do_thing(int x) {f(x);};
};

int main()
{
    auto f = [](int x) {std::cout << x << std::endl;};
    K kl{f};
    kl.do_thing(5);

    return 0;
}
```

however I would like to perform some check in the constructor of the class `K` (for instance some `std::is_convertible_v` inside some `bool` function), so I tried to modify the code to

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Func>
class K {
    Func f;
    
public:
    K(Func _f) {
    ...
    f = _f;};
    void do_thing(int x) {f(x);};
};

int main()
{
    auto f = [](int x) {std::cout << x << std::endl;};
    K kl{f};
    kl.do_thing(5);

    return 0;
}
```

which however gives me some error message

```
error: use of deleted function ‘main()::<lambda(int)>::<lambda>()’
```

and then

```
note: a lambda closure type has a deleted default constructor
```

This confuses me a lot since I cannot understand how it is possible that the former piece of code could compile since the lambda function has not default constructor.

**Question**
How can I set my `f` *inside* the body of the constructor? (This is just a MWE and in my case the class is a bit more complex and the checks I mentioned before make sense.)

Comment: you cannot initialize the member in the body of the constructor. It is initialized before the body of the constructor is executed.

Comment: I see, so how can I set the f to be the same as _f inside the body, after the checks I have to do?

Comment: I dont quite understand your motivation. What kind of checks can you do with the second version of the code that you cannot do with the first?

Comment: I want to check for signature of that function and if the signature is not what I expect I set `f` to be some default function (according to some other parameters I have in the class. Here those parameters do not appear since is a MWE).

Comment: sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your complete code will have more issues because each lamda expression has a unique type. Maybe ask for the actual problem you are trying to solve, but consider that this question already has an answer, so perhaps open a new one

Comment: you could use SFINAE to check the right signature, then initializing the lambda in the initializer list is fine.

Comment: As side note: `f = _f;` is super confusing; Normally class fields have names with underscore, not method arguments.

Comment: "_I would like to perform some check in the constructor of the class `K`_" - Should this check have an effect on the initialization of `f`? If so, can you describe a little bit about what you want?

Comment: To put my question in other words: Why not initialize it in the member initializer list?

Answer (score 5):

> How can I initialize my `f` inside the body of the constructor?

You can't. `f = _f;` inside the constructor body is assignment but not initialization. So `f` will be default-initialized firstly, then enter the constructor body (to perform assignment).

You might use `std::function` instead; which could be default-initialized, then you can assign it in constructor body.

---

BTW: Since C++20 your code will compile fine even it might not work as you expected (depending on the `...` part). For [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda),

> If no *captures* are specified, the closure type has a defaulted default constructor. Otherwise, it has no default constructor (this includes the case when there is a *capture-default*, even if it does not actually capture anything).

Comment: it will compile, but I am not sure if it achieves what OP wants to achieve by that modification of their code

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, it depends on how the check is performed and what should be performed when check fails.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
It is the generic solution, not making any assumptions on the signature of Fn

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename Fn>
class K
{
public:
    explicit K(const Fn& fn) :
        m_fn{ fn }
    {
    };

    template<typename... args_t>
    auto do_thing(args_t&&... args)
    {
        return m_fn(std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
    }

private:
    Fn m_fn;

};

int main()
{
    auto f = [](int x) {std::cout << x << std::endl; };
    K kl{ f };
    kl.do_thing(5);
}
```